# Applying function to groups in dataframe, excluding current row value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, statistics

Let's say I have the following data:

| day | query | num_searches |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | abc | 2 |
| 1 | def | 3 |
| 2 | abc | 6 |
| 3 | abc | 5 |
| 4 | def | 1 |
| 4 | abc | 3 |
| 5 | abc | 7 |
| 6 | abc | 8 |
| 7 | abc | 10 |
| 8 | abc | 1 |

I'd like to generate z-score (excluding the current row's value) such that for query 'abc':

```
Day 1: [6, 5, 3, 7, 8, 10, 1] (exclude the value 2) zscore = -1.32
Day 2: [2, 5, 3, 7, 8, 10, 1] (exclude the value 6) zscore = 0.28
...
Day 7: [2, 6, 5, 3, 7, 8, 1] (exclude the value 10) zscore = 2.22
Day 8: [2, 6, 5, 3, 7, 8, 10] (exclude the value 1) zscore = -1.88
```

I have the following function to calculate this 'exclusive' zscore.

```
def zscore_exclusive(arr):
    newl = []
    for index, val in enumerate(x):
        l = list(x)
        val = l.pop(index)
        arr_popped = np.array(l)
        avg = np.mean(arr_popped)
        stdev = np.std(arr_popped)        
        newl.append((val - avg) / stdev)
    return np.array(newl)
```

How can I apply this custom function to each grouping (by query string)? Remember, I'd like to pop the currently evaluated element from the series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given:

```
   day query  num_searches
0    1   abc             2
1    1   def             3
2    2   abc             6
3    3   abc             5
4    4   def             1
5    4   abc             3
6    5   abc             7
7    6   abc             8
8    7   abc            10
9    8   abc             1
```

Doing:

- **Note!**

  - For `np.std`, `ddof = 0` by default.
  - But for `pd.Series.std`, `ddof = 1` by default.

    - You should be sure which one you want to use.

```
z_score = lambda x: [(x[i]-x.drop(i).mean())/x.drop(i).std(ddof=0) for i in x.index]
df['z-score'] = df.groupby('query')['num_searches'].transform(z_score)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   day query  num_searches   z-score
0    1   abc             2 -1.319950
1    1   def             3       inf
2    2   abc             6  0.277350
3    3   abc             5 -0.092057
4    4   def             1      -inf
5    4   abc             3 -0.866025
6    5   abc             7  0.661438
7    6   abc             8  1.083862
8    7   abc            10  2.223782
9    8   abc             1 -1.877336
```

Comment: Thanks! I've noticed that scipy.stats.zscore doesn't seem to include an option to exclude each value from the mean/stdev calculation. Is this because it isn't appropriate to approach the z-score calculation in this way?

Comment: That sounds like a question that those over at https://stats.stackexchange.com may be better at answering~